# Mock Orange Fragrance

Tags: shrubs

My mock orange flowered this spring following my bare root purchase last season.  However, we are losing the blooms, but it never provided a fragrance.

Comment: Mock orange usually refers to Philadelphus sp. - is that the shrub you refer to?